# See if strings in list are a part of strings in another list. Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to find out if a list of strings are also part of strings in another list.

I've found this so far but I'm not able to get what I actually want.

```
a = ["car", "book","chair"]
b = ["car", "oldbook", "bluechair"]
c = [elem for elem in a if elem in b]
print(c)
```

this will print ['car'].

I would like to have a way to print 'book' and 'chair' as well because 'book' is a part of 'oldbook' and 'chair' of 'bluechair'.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) here:

```
>>> a = ["car", "book","chair"]
>>> b = ["car", "oldbook", "bluechair"]
>>> [elem for elem in a if any(elem in x for x in b)]
['car', 'book', 'chair']
```

This works since it keeps strings in `a` that exist in any string in `b`.